# std::function argument types

Tags: c++, c++14

If you check [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), you'll see that `std::function` ought to define some optional types, quoted for your convenience:

```
Member types
Type                  Definition
result_type           R
argument_type         T if sizeof...(Args)==1 and T is the first and only type in Args...
first_argument_type   T1 if sizeof...(Args)==2 and T1 is the first of the two types in Args...
second_argument_type  T2 if sizeof...(Args)==2 and T2 is the second of the two types in Args...
```

How would one go about implementing this requirement? My first thought was  to conditionally inherit a struct defining the types for the 2 possible cases, but are there other, nicer ways to go about it, that don't involve inheriting? I am not interested in type erasure or any other functionality `std::function` offers.

Comment: What's non-nice in inheriting?

Comment: you need to define 2 extra classes/structs. I find it cumbersome and I'd really like to see if there's are alternative ways, just to learn about them.

Comment: You will probably have to define extra helper structs anyway.

Comment: @n.m. So you think inheriting is _the_ nicest way to go about this?

Comment: @user1095108 inheritance from a specialized class template, or specializing the `std::function` itself, I can't see other options

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki or one could also use `std::conditional` and inherit from non-specialized struct/class templates. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least on Visual C++, inheritance is how they do it:

`std::function` inherits from `_Get_function_impl` class.
`_Get_function_impl` type-defines `_Func_class<_Ret, _Types...>` as `type`.
`_Func_class` inherits from `_Fun_class_base`

`_Fun_class_base` may inherit conditionly from `unary_function` , `binary_function` or non - if there are no arguments or there are more than 2 arguments.

`unary_function` and `binary_function` type-defines the wanted types.

so yeah.. inheritance is the way the Microsoft team choose, I don't see why not?

Comment: *"may inherit conditionly from `unary_function`, `binary_function`"*, except that both are deprecated in C++11 and will be removed in C++1z

Comment: I'm not the manager of MSVC++ team. I'm just telling how they implemented it.

Answer (score 2):

How about specializing your data structure according to the template arguments:

```
template <typename...Args>
struct test
{

};

template <typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
struct test<Arg1, Arg2> //specialization for sizeof...(Args)==2
{
    using first_argument_type = Arg1;
    using second_argument_type = Arg2;

};

template <typename Arg1>
struct test<Arg1> //specialization for sizeof...(Args)==1
{
    using argument_type = Arg1;
};


int main()
{
    //test<int, char, std::string>::argument_type t31;          //NOK
    //test<int, char, std::string>::first_argument_type t32;    //NOK
    //test<int, char, std::string>::second_argument_type t33;   //NOK
    //test<int, char>::argument_type t21;                       //NOK
    test<int, char>::first_argument_type t22;                   //OK
    test<int, char>::second_argument_type t23;                  //OK
    test<int>::argument_type t11;                               //OK
    //test<int>::first_argument_type t11;                       //NOK
    //test<int>::second_argument_type t11;                      //NOK
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems cumbersome too, but +1 for a nice idea.

Comment: You don't need the `typename` keywords here before `ArgN`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I know yet I'm currently starting to always add them to prevent failures because of this. It doesn't hurt afaik ;-)

Comment: @SimonKraemer you'll never get a failure for non-dependent names

Comment: It's not just you don't need it, it's actually syntactically invalid.

Comment: @T.C. It is? Could you provide me some more information about why? I'll adjust my answer if this might cause problems...

Comment: [*typename-specifier*s](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#3) must contain a *nested-name-specifier* (i.e., must have `::` somewhere in it). Both clang and GCC rejects your code for this reason.

Comment: @T.C. Thank you for the link. I adjusted my answer.